# Screen Blanks out, Mouse and Keyboard stop working

Tags: windows-7, boot, gpu

I have a pc with Windows 7 and an external GPU. Whenever I try to boot the PC, it boots up successfully but suddenly freezes after about 20 seconds of viewing the desktop. The screen shows some rectangular grid, and the mouse and keyboard become unresponsive. 
The computer works fine in safe mode. If I remove the external GPU, then the computer works fine. 
Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: Have you looked at updated drivers for your GPU?

Comment: Actually it was working fine when I tried to use it last summer with the same drivers.. Still how should I try to update if the pc doesnt start up?

Comment: Not all drivers will let you do this, but look into installing updated drivers with the GPU out/disabled (i.e. some drivers will not install w/o the device present), then install. Can also look into installing drivers in Safe Mode.

Comment: Okay, I will try to do that.. But the gpu worked with the exact same drivers when I tried to use it last summer.